# Place UIButton on the top of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, storyboard

I plan to have a view controller, a table view (3 sections) and 3 button. I don't know whether I can place the button 1 in the table view and on the top of the table view (exactly on top of section 1), button 2 is on top of section 2 and button 3 is on top of section 3.

And I also want when people scroll down, button 1 will still on top until it meet button 2 -> button 2 will be on top and when it meet button 3, button 3 will be on top.

Could you help me do what I want?

Comment: Fix what? I don't see any half-working code.

Comment: What do you mean with "on top of section"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I tried it. I replaced the header of section 1 by button 1. But I can replace only button 1. I can't replace the header of section 2, 3 by button 2, 3. I want to do that because I want to set 3 sections hidden by default. When people click buttons, sections will appear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: stop **planing** and try something with code, and come back for assistance when you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that may work for your purpose. In your `UITableViewController`, which should also be your `UITableViewDelegate`, implement the following code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIButton *button = nil;
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, BUTTON1_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(SELECTOR1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            // do some more things
            break;
        case 1:
            button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, BUTTON2_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(SELECTOR2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            // do some more things
            break;
        case 2:
            button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, BUTTON3_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(SELECTOR3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            // do some more things
            break;
        default:
            // do default things
            break;
    }

    [headerView addSubview:button];
    return headerView;
}
```

And don't forget to implement this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return HEADER_HEIGHT;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your solution and come back if I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Use bringSubviewToFront: method and write following code in viewDidLoad method.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.